# Why does this impulse not affect the body?

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I'm just getting started with Box2d and I'm trying to apply an impulse to a circle but nothing really happens.

First I define `ball`:

```
BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
bodyDef.position.set(camera.viewportWidth / 2, camera.viewportHeight / 2);
ball = world.createBody(bodyDef);
CircleShape dynamicCircle = new CircleShape();
dynamicCircle.setRadius(50f);
FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
fixtureDef.shape = dynamicCircle;
fixtureDef.density = 0.5f;
fixtureDef.friction = 0.4f;
fixtureDef.restitution = 0.6f;
ball.createFixture(fixtureDef);
dynamicCircle.dispose();
```

then I call this line from inside my `inputprocessor`

```
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    Gdx.app.log("input", "touchDown");
    ball.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0f, 5000f), ball.getPosition(), true);
    return true;
}
```

Here's the render method:

```
public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    debugRenderer.render(world, camera.combined);
    world.step(1 / 60f, 6, 2);
}
```

I tried logging this and can confirm the `touchDown` event is triggered, but the impulse never applies.

Am I forgetting some call to make this work? What might be going wrong?

Comment: Is `world.step` called?

Comment: @Anko only in my render method.

Comment: OK. Unless it logs errors, I think the force should be applying then. Hmm. Potential clue: Box2D's maths are tuned for "moving objects roughly between 0.1 and 10 meters" ([the manual](http://www.box2d.org/manual.html) § 1.7 Units). You might want to reduce the currently `50f`-meter radius of the `dynamicCircle` just in case the applied force is getting discarded by an approximation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line

```
ball.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0f, 5000f), ball.getPosition(), true);
```

I think the point where you put force it relative to object position, so you put impule in

```
ball.getPosition() + ball.getPosition()
```

Try to use

```
public void applyForceToCenter(Vector2 force, boolean wake)
```

or

```
ball.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0f, 5000f), new Vector(0,0), true);
```

Didn't test.

Comment: applying impulse to the center works! but the ball doesn't go up, it rotates instead. is this normal?

Comment: ball.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0f, 5000f), ball.getLocalCenter(), true);